# Windows Credential Manager unexpectedly restores previous state on reboot

Tags: networking, windows-7, credentials

After deleting all existing credentials in Windows Credential Manager, and adding a single, new Windows credential by IP with Enterprise persistence, the new state of Credential Manager (with one new credential) is maintained for between 1 and 8 days/restart cycles. At random though, about 1/3 of the time, when I reboot the computer, the previous (at this point several months out of date) state of Credential Manager is mysteriously restored. The new credential is deleted, and all the previous credentials including ones to servers that don't exist any more have been restored.

What is happening here?

- Is there any way to force Windows to actually permanently delete these old credentials, or at least prevent them from randomly reappearing?
- Is there any way to create a new credential that will survive the mysterious random restoring process?
- What actually triggers this? (At present, it may as well be RNG.)